# App crashes on Android 8.0.0 : libandroid_runtime.so unknown

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

Since our last release, this libandroid_runtime.so unknown crash became our top crash. It happens only on Android 8.0.0, and mostly on Samsung devices(99%).
Here is the crash info we got from Fabric crashlytics:

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libandroid_runtime.so          0x72e1cc64a4 (Missing)
1  libandroid_runtime.so          0x72e1cc6468 (Missing)
2  libminikin.so                  0x6ffc6fcc (Missing)
3  libminikin.so                  0x132400cc (Missing)
4  libminikin.so                  0x1324073c (Missing)
5  libminikin.so                  0x1324039c (Missing)
6  libminikin.so                  0x6fab1b04 (Missing)
7  (Missing)                      0x735736ec (Missing)
8  libminikin.so                  0x1324038c (Missing)
9  libminikin.so                  0x6fc31c9c (Missing)
10 libminikin.so                  0x6f6b78b4 (Missing)
11 libminikin.so                  0x6fc31c74 (Missing)
12 boot-framework.oat             0x71f9736c (Missing)
13 libminikin.so                  0x6ffc6cfc (Missing)
14 libminikin.so                  0x6f6b78b4 (Missing)
15 libminikin.so                  0x1324038c (Missing)
16 libminikin.so                  0x13240094 (Missing)
17 libminikin.so                  0x132400cc (Missing)
18 libminikin.so                  0x12f7ff0c (Missing)
19 libminikin.so                  0x13240094 (Missing)
20 libminikin.so                  0x6fab1b04 (Missing)
21 boot-framework.oat             0x71f97670 (Missing)
22 libminikin.so                  0x6ffc6d5c (Missing)
23 libminikin.so                  0x6f75439c (Missing)
24 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
25 libminikin.so                  0x12f7ff0c (Missing)
26 boot-framework.oat             0x71f95ca0 (Missing)
27 libminikin.so                  0x6ffc6c0c (Missing)
28 (Missing)                      0x9b878924 (Missing)
29 libminikin.so                  0x12cf07a4 (Missing)
30 libminikin.so                  0x12f7d23c (Missing)
31 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
32 libminikin.so                  0x12ceabdc (Missing)
33 libminikin.so                  0x12f62474 (Missing)
34 libminikin.so                  0x12f62494 (Missing)
35 libminikin.so                  0x12f7a32c (Missing)
36 libminikin.so                  0x12f7a364 (Missing)
37 libminikin.so                  0x12f7d23c (Missing)
38 libminikin.so                  0x13bd4764 (Missing)
39 libminikin.so                  0x12c5ad94 (Missing)
40 boot-framework.oat             0x71b177e4 (Missing)
41 libminikin.so                  0x6fdf9834 (Missing)
42 libminikin.so                  0x12f7d3ec (Missing)
43 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
44 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
45 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
46 libminikin.so                  0x12cc04b4 (Missing)
47 base.odex                      0x72c3f339e0 (Missing)
48 (Missing)                      0x9b88fa6c (Missing)
49 libminikin.so                  0x13c8364c (Missing)
```

Would really appreciate any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue.
Thanks,

Jiusong

Comment: Can you share more information? Like does it happen during app launch or while performing certain action? Is there any background services running? What observations do you have while debugging the application?

Comment: Hi Soumya, thanks for your reply. 
I wish I could have more info about this crash. But I don't know how to reproduce it.
All the crash info I have now is coming from Fabric Crashlytics. Looks like sometimes it happens during app's launch.

Comment: Hi Jiusong, are you using NDK?

Comment: Hi buser, we do have a feature running on native code, but it's been turned off for a while. And from the Crashlytics info, I can tell it's not happening in our native code.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. Could you reach out to us with more details: support(at)fabric(dot)io and we can debug further there?

Comment: Hi buser, I did contact Fabric, but they told me " this is the most level of detail that we have for this crash. Unfortunately if the crash is happening when Samsung is loading information from it's own libraries, we don't have a way to get the symbols for those crashes."